# Implementing Satellite Menu for Android ( classes could not be instantiated)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I added this object to my xml layout

```
 <android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    sat:closeOnClick="true"
    sat:expandDuration="500"
    sat:mainImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    sat:satelliteDistance="170dp"
    sat:totalSpacingDegree="90" >
</android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu>
```

and recieve this error :

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

so i look in Log and i got these details

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F030015.
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getLayout(BridgeResources.java:271)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu.init(SatelliteMenu.java:78)
    at android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu.<init>(SatelliteMenu.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderPreview.renderSync(RenderPreview.java:560)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderPreview.access$5(RenderPreview.java:506)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderPreview$RenderJob.runInUIThread(RenderPreview.java:1230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414
```

)

that this mean ?

when i run this project in the first time the object work fine and after this it do troubles

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION #1:**

Sometimes, when a new resource is added, Eclipse doesn't compile correctly the new code (maybe a caching issue), causing this error.

Normally, simply restarting Eclipse is enough to fix the problem.

**OPTION #2:**

Sometimes, rendering custom views causes this exception. The only workaround I know is checking View.isInEditMode every time you try to use the `getResources()`.

An example could be:

```
if (isInEditMode()) {
    //do something else, as getResources() is not valid.
} else {
    //you can use getResources()
    String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
}
```